# A simple question about continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $g\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $(\alpha_0, \beta_0)$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $g$ is a continuous function $g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$ and $g^{-1}(\{\beta_0)\}$ are closed set in $[a,b]$. We define now $$a_0:=\max g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$$ and $$b_0:=\min g^{-1}(\{\beta_0\}$$

> Why for the continuity of $g$ we have that $g(a_0)=\alpha_0$ and $g(b_0)=\beta_0$?

Comment: Think about why the minimum/maximum exists.

Comment: It's true by definition of the preimage. So all you need to do is ensure the maximum and minimum exist. This occurs because the preimages are closed and the function is continuous.

Comment: The only way that this would be tricky is if you replaced "max" and "min" with "sup" and "inf", but since $a_0 \in g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$, you have that $g(a_0) = \alpha_0$ by definition.

Comment: The preimages of the boundary points may be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The continuity of $g$ gives that $\max g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$ and $\min g^{-1}(\{\beta_0)\}$ exist, and your question is answered just by definition of preimage.

If we have a subset $A$ of reals numbers, before saying that that $x$ and $y$ are, respectivily, the minimum and the maximum of $A$, we need to ensure that
$\sup A$ and $\inf A$ exist. Because the minimum and the maximum of $A$ are just the supremum and the infimum when belong to $A$. For this, we need that $A$ is bounded below and above.

So...

Because of the continuity of $g$, $g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$ and $g^{-1}(\{\beta_0)\}$ are closed sets in $[a,b]$, then are bounded sets (below and above), therefore $\sup g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$ and $\inf g^{-1}(\{\beta_0)\}$ are both defined. Due to $g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})$ and $g^{-1}(\{\beta_0)\}$ are closed, we have
\begin{align*}
\sup g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\}) \in g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})
\Rightarrow
\sup g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\}) = \max g^{-1}(\{\alpha_0\})
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\inf g^{-1}(\{\beta_0\}) \in g^{-1}(\{\beta_0\})
\Rightarrow
\inf g^{-1}(\{\beta_0\}) = \min g^{-1}(\{\beta_0\})
\end{align*}
(you can check theorem 2.28 Principles of mathematical analysis third edition by Walter Rudin, although is intituive)

Finally we have $g(a_0) = \alpha_0$ and $g(b_0) = \beta_0$ just by definition of preimage.